# Regulator not fitting CO2 tank

Tags: carbonation, equipment, co2, gas, help

I recently started gathering equipment for home water carbonation and collected my CO2 tank today to find the regulator I purchased does not fit it.

I am based in Ireland, here is the regulator I purchased: 
https://www.schankanlagen-koch.de/AfG-Hauptdruckminderer-CO2-Druckminderer-Hauptdruckregler-HIWI-Euskirchen-3-bar-1499.html

[image: Hiwi Euskirchen CO2 Regulator]

And here is the gas tank:

[image: CO2 Gas tank]

As you can see the fittings are completely different, the tank has a female connection while the regulator expects a male. The regulator is for CO2 and the tank is pure CO2 not a mixture or other gas...what have I done wrong? Can I get an adaptor?

Comment: In my experience, even getting parts and gas cylinders *in the same country* (US) to fit can be tricky. I can imagine trying to find a foreign regulator to fit a local cylinder would be a headache. The issue is that so many localities have their own standards for outlet fitting styles (see: http://hiq.linde-gas.com/en/specialty_gases/specialty_gases_cylinder_outlets.html). All I can say is, if you're lucky, they're both some sort of DIN fitting (e.g. http://www.gascon.com.au/content/products/pdf/Valve_Summary_DIN477.pdf), you'll just need to find out exactly which ones (I couldn't).

Comment: In my experience in homebrewing and bar work there is meant to be a hose between the regulator and the gas tank. The hose fits one end to the regulator and the other end to the gas canister. I'm not sure of that brand of regulator but you may want to find out if there is a regulator hose that fits to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some companies use mixed gas hardware for CO2 gas, this is a mixed gas (argon/CO2) fitting and needs a different connection to a standard CO2 fitting.

Adapters are available and the gas company should be able to advise.

Comment: Tried to make this answer generic, contacted the company and they are sending out an adapter. they use mixed gas tanks for their co2, presumably this is easier for welders etc who probably already have mixed gas regulators for other gasses.